# Meta-analysis model

Tags: meta-analysis

I have a dataset which includes different publications, and different studies within each publication,
running fixed and random effect model for the same data for all studies, both models reported the same effect size and heterogeneity, however for the random model, se, CIs are larger.

Is this normal, is this means that I don't have within study variations?

Comment: Yes, it is likely to happen. If you re-read the tutorial material you used when you learned about meta-analysis and look specifically at the formulae for the two models you should easily see what is going on.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you so much for your response, I appreciate that